# conditional rendering to display in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

I wanted to display badge/text after which condition is met from two conditions.
First condition is that if no **openSopts** available then show **SOLD OUT** badge/text and if this condition is not met then check if it is online and then show badge/text of **ONLINE**.
But badge/text is not shown on card component, can you please tell me what mistake i am doing ?

Comment: Please include code as text not images. Also, a `<div>` JSX element needs to be used, a statement like `if(true){<div />}` doesn't actually do anything, it's the same as `if(true){1}`, the value has to be assigned to something or used in some way.

Comment: You can use ```helper function``` or ternary syntax to render as well, as ```{props.openSpots === 0 ? <div className="card--badge"> SOLD OUT </div> : <div className="card--badge"> online </div> }```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSX being returned does not include the JSX in your `if`/`else` statement. It needs to be part of the JSX that's returned in order for it to show up.

You could use ternary expressions to do it like this (add this to the JSX after your `return` statement, put it wherever you'd like the badge rendered):

```
{ props.openSpots === 0 ? <div className="card--badge">SOLD OUT</div> : null }
{ props.openSpots > 0 && props.location === "Online" ? <div className="card--badge">Online</div> : null }
```

You could nest them if you wanted a single statement, but that starts to get [difficult to read](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-nested-ternary):

```
{
   props.openSpots === 0 
      ? <div className="card--badge">SOLD OUT</div> 
      : props.location === "Online" 
         ? <div className="card--badge">Online</div> 
         : null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the JSX in the rendering part, its just a statement.

Either save the JSX in variable like this:

```
let badge = null

if (openSpots === 0) {
badge = ..
} else if (..) {
badge = ..
}

// Use it in code 

...
<div class="card-badge">{badge}</div>
```

Or use conditional rendering inline

Comment: This will render the `div` regardless (even when `openSpots > 0` and `location !== "Online"`), which may not be intended.

Comment: Maybe removee the `<div>`  would work, couldnt copy the code since it was image, that's why just added it quickly

Answer (score 0):

Just assign your code piece to a variable and then render it wherever you want.

```
...
const badge = openSpots === 0 ? <div className="card--badge">SOLD OUT</div> : <div className="card--badge">Online</div>
...
return (
  <div>
   {badge}
  </div>
);
```